# Java iterating through MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, database

In java using JDBC I am trying to connect to 3 databases I created in MySQL. Below is a snippet of what each database looks like and their keys. Left table is titled 'bets, right 'players' and bottom 'standings'.

[image: 3 databases with keys]

I want to extract from the tables each players bet/position for 1 bet.

For instance a simple System.out.println that will says "For bet 1, player (player_id) came in (position) and bet on player (player_id)".

I've done initally a simple variation of this

```
String standingsTable = CreateStatement.CreateStatement("*", "standings", null);

PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(standingsTable);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

while (rs.next()) {
   int betsID = rs.getInt("bets_id");
   int playerID = rs.getInt("players_id");
   int position = rs.getInt("position");
   int playerBet = (rs.getInt("player_bet"));

   System.out.println("Bet " + betsID + " player " + playerID + " finished " + position + " and voted for " + playerBet ); }
```

However this would print out the below results

[image: Code results]

If possible I instead would want one line to be like

"Bet 1 player 1 finished 0 and voted for 3, player 2 finished 1 and voted for 1, player 3 finished 2 and voted for 2".

So to have each players record for each bet as a unit rather than 3 seperate entries. If i'm not making it clear enough please say and I will try to clear it up further what I'm requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want grouping players, if there are same bets_id?
If this is right, see below code

```java
        while (rs.next()) {
            int betsID = rs.getInt("bets_id");
            int playerID = rs.getInt("players_id");
            int position = rs.getInt("position");
            int playerBet = (rs.getInt("player_bet"));
            
            StringBuilder sb = null;
            
            if (records.containsKey(betsID)) {
                sb = records.get(betsID);
            } else {
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }

            sb.append(" player " + playerID + " finished " + position + " and voted for " + playerBet);

            records.put(betsID, sb);
        }

        records.forEach((key, value) -> {
            System.out.println("Bets " + key + value);
        });
```